# difference between exponential and log functions for numpy and math

Tags: math, numpy, logging

This sounds like a naive question, but I can't figure out why there are two instances of functions like e, log etc., one for each numpy and math. For example numpy.e and math.e give me exactly the same result 2.71828....... What's the reason for this duplication?

Comment: Possibly so the two libraries can be reasonably self-contained. You can't do too much *without* e and log.

Comment: I see. So this means I could use the two interchangeably at will?

Comment: @Bathsheba: Agreed about `log`, but I'd beg to differ about `e`, which IMO is a bit of an attractive nuisance: you see people using `e` to write `e ** x`, which is significantly less accurate than `exp(x)`.  If it were up to me, I'd have `e` removed from the standard library: on the rare occasions that someone actually needs the *constant* `e` rather than the exponential *function* `exp`, it can be computed as `exp(1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy` functions are called `ufunc`, you can use them on `numpy` array:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.exp (numpy.array([1, 2, 3]))
array([  2.71828183,   7.3890561 ,  20.08553692])
```

`math` functions are standard function (part of the standard python library), so they can be used only on standard types (such as `int` or `float`).

`numpy` functions are much more powerful than the math ones (when working on vector / matrix / etc.), but `numpy` is not a standard library.

If you check the `type` of the `exp` function, you get the following:

```
>>> type(numpy.exp)
numpy.ufunc
>>> type(math.exp)
builtin_function_or_method
```

Where you can see that `numpy` has defined its own `exp` function, whereas the `math.exp` function is `builtin`.

You **cannot** use them interchangeably at will: `numpy.exp` will work where `math.exp` works, but the inverse is not true (`math.exp([1, 2, 3])` fails).

Comment: What about types like `numpy.float128` ? would `math.exp(numpy.float128(2))` convert the argument to a standard float and also return a standard float?

Comment: @Falk Most likely, since `numpy.float128` overloads `__float__`, so it should be equivalent to `math.exp(float(numpy.float128(...)))`.

Comment: Well, the thing with float128 is that it's expected to hold a 128 bit floating point number, not just a 32 bit one. So it should be different things. My fear is that the implementation of the math library might cast one type to the other one.

Comment: @Falk Obviously you're going to loose precision if you call `math.exp` with a 128-bits float since it will be first converted to a 32-bits Python `float`.